# running consecutively thread groups in JMeter dosnt work

Tags: jmeter

I need write the following scenario in JMeter
Login via http request and in parallel sending calls for 8 hours.
After that running in parallel Login and Logoff and sending calls again for 8 hours
After that running in parallel Login and Logoff and sending calls again for 8 hours
After that running in parallel Login and Logoff and sending calls again for 8 hours
and after N runs … start everything from beginning.

I created N thread groups , and added parallel controller , and under the parallel controller i added the loop controller of Login , Logout, sending calls

it didn't worked , the test stops after running the first run of thread group, it doesn't run as duration time .
what i m doing wrong , maybe i have to write the test plan different?

Comment: Hi @Leon , Can you please inlude screenshots of your threadgroup and loop controller etc to see the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot say anything meaningful without seeing your [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration, for now I can only state that your test will end when:

1. the last user finishes the last iteration specified in the Loop Count
2. the test duration exceeds the "Duration"

whatever comes the first.

So make sure to tick "Infinite" box and specify the desired duration of your test plan

[image]

Also be aware that according to the [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) the Parallel Controller runs its children in parallel. **Once**. The main use case for the parallel controller is simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests to bypass JMeter's limitation of "one virtual user = one thread", maybe for your test scenario it makes sense to increase the number of threads in the Thread Group instead of going for Parallel Controller.

And last but not the least, be aware of the [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which executes its children for the specified duration.